# Can't Do Math on Column If Some Rows Are of Type String

Tags: python, pandas

Here is a sample of my df:

```
    units                      price
0   143280.0                   0.8567                        
1   4654.0                    464.912                       
2   512210.0                   607  
3  Unknown                    0                          
4  Unknown                    0
```

I have the following code:

```
myDf.loc[(myDf["units"].str.isnumeric())&(myDf["price"].str.isnumeric()),'newValue']=(    
myDf["price"].astype(float).fillna(0.0)*
myDf["units"].astype(float).fillna(0.0)/
1000)
```

As you can see, I'm trying to only do math to create the 'newValue' column for rows where the two source columns are both numeric. However, I get the following error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Unknown'
```

So it seems that even though I'm attempting to perform math only on the rows that don't have text, Pandas does not like that any of the rows have text.

Note that I need to maintain the instances of "Unknown" exactly as they are and so filling those with zero is not a good option.

This has be pretty stumped. Could not find any solutions by searching Google.

Would appreciate any help/solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same condition you use on the left side of the `=` on the right side as follows (I set the condition in a variable `is_num` for readability):

```
is_num = (myDf["units"].astype(str).str.replace('.', '').str.isnumeric()) & (myDf["price"].astype(str).str.replace('.', '').str.isnumeric())
myDf.loc[is_num,'newValue']=( 
       myDf.loc[is_num, "price"].astype(float).fillna(0.0)* 
       myDf.loc[is_num, "units"].astype(float).fillna(0.0)/1000)
```

Also, you need to check with your read dataframe, but from this example, you can:

1. Remove the `fillna(0.0)`, since there are no `NaN`s
2. Remove the checks on 'price' (as of your example, price is always numeric, so the check is not necessary)
3. Remove the `astype(float)` cast for price, since it's already numeric.

That would lead to the following somewhat more concise code:

```
is_num = myDf["units"].astype(str).str.replace('.', '').str.isnumeric()
myDf.loc[is_num,'newValue']=( 
       myDf.loc[is_num, "price"].astype(float)* 
       myDf.loc[is_num, "units"]/1000)
```

Comment: Sadly does not work.  Gives error `AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas
`

Comment: Thanks Jullian. That makes sense to me. Tried and now I am getting: TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed

Comment: myDf = pd.DataFrame({'units' : [143280.0, 4654.0, 512210.0, 'Unknown', 'Unknown'],
              'price' : [0.8567, 464.912, 607, 0, 0]})

Comment: Hi! I just checked the code. You can add a `astype(str)` to cast all the column values to strings before doing the `.str` access. I'm editing my answer with the functioning version.

Comment: Now all values of 'newValue' are NaN.

Comment: `is_num` is all False

Comment: You are right: `isnumeric()` doesn't work as I thought. I'm adding a solution `.str.replace(".", '').str.isnumeric()` to the answer.

Comment: Nice. Thanks @astro123!

Comment: Thanks, Guys!!! This all made sense and it works!!!!  Note that I ended up also replacing spaces within is_num because in some cases spaces turned out to be in the data in addition to periods. Can't thank you guys enough!!!!